# How to save Modal Dialog width is browser session?

Tags: javascript, oracle, modal-dialog, oracle-apex

I want to save the Modal Dialog width in browser session state.

I enabled the `resizable: true` for the modal dialog page, and the modal dialog is resizable now.

So, I want to save the width in a session so that I shouldn't change the width every time I open the modal page.

I am using Oracle APEX 21.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your code (as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) along with what you've tried so far, you might also find [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052) helpful for next time.

Comment: You can achieve this using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage); When the modal is resized, save the new dimensions with `localStorage.setItem('modalSize', currentWidth);`, then next time the page is loaded, get the modal size with `const modalSize = localStorage.getItem('modalSize');`. But without any of your code, it's not possible to provide a more detailed example.

Comment: Thanks @lissy93, I was following the this post: [link](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2015/06/25/how-to-persist-apex-dialog-size-and-position/) and it doesn't work for me, probably because I am on newer version of APEX. There is some code for newer version, but I don't know where should I add that code.